# How can I check file size of uploaded file using multer

Tags: node.js, upload, multer

I am using multer for file uploading and i am uploading multiple file at time and it's working,but I want to set each file size limit and all files combine limit. How can I set this?

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/images/uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log("========>", file.originalname)
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    },
    // fileFilter: fileFilter
})
```

Comment: what you have currently done (limits with filesize) should work, isnt-it ? can you upload any file heavier than 1024*1024 ?

Comment: @Kepotx Yes this is work with uploading file less then 1024X1024 (1mb)